# CSS positioning full width and height of multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, positioning

Good evening gentlemen (and of course ladies),

I'm currently experiencing some problems with CSS and the dynamic positioning of some elements in one big container. And I hoped that anyone of you could probably know the solution for my problem.

Maybe I just start with the explanation, which I will split in three parts to make it easier to understand. In the end of this post, there are two links, one for the steps to visualize them and one for the example jsfiddle for step two.

**Step one:** 
There is one `div.container` which has the height `255px` and a dynamic width of `33.3%`. This container contains two divs: `div.left` and `div.right`. The `div.left` has exactly `150px` width, which should bring the `div.right` to fill up the whole remaining space.

I already tried to solve it this way, which works, but not for the next steps.

```
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}

.right {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Step two**:  Now, there should be three different elements in the `div.right`, a `h3`, `span` and `p` element. The `h3` and `span` should just behave like a regular element, and use the space they want to use (like for displaying text). But the `p` element should take the whole remaining height of the `div.right`. I achieved this single step by using the code in the jsfiddle link in the end of this post. And it looks really cool, but it's not compatible with the next step. As you maybe already guessed it.

**Step three**:
As the `p.description` element contains a description, I want to put as much information into this small element as possible. Therefor, I hoped to use `overflow:hidden` in combination with `text-overflow:ellipsis`, but this didn't work. Due to some strange reason, the `p.description` element was placed right of the `h3` and `span` elements after I added the `overflow:hidden` style. 
And additionally, there is an extra div in the footer of the `div.right`, which is `div.btns`. This `div` contains about 3 plain links and is placed absolutely in the right bottom of `div.right`, and I only want to have the `p.description` element to wrap the text around it.

Right now, I doubt, that all of these steps are solvable by only using css. At least, I wanted to have the positioning of the elements with css and the truncating of the text could be done in Javascript.

Is there anybody out there, who has an idea, how I could solve my problem?

Many thanks in advance!

**Attachments**:

- All three steps in one picture: http://cl.ly/image/2t2a3o3o2l0s/steps.png
- JsFiddle for step two: http://jsfiddle.net/S8g4E/1188/

Comment: The jsfiddle gave me a security error when I viewed it from work. Also, the html / css in the fiddle doesn't match with this posting.

Comment: Strange, the jsfiddle link works perfectly fine for me :( So I will just copy it here: http://nopaste.info/b8debfa8d7.html

Comment: The code in the question doesn't match that which you link to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mohamed_nabil/7btp2/

In css: the max-height of the ellipsis in lines(52 & 61) are now 200px,
this can be changed with jQuery if you want to, on window resize or load.

```
max-height: 200px; /*This value could be changed with jquery*/
```

Comment: You sir, are great! This is exactly what I tried to achieve and it works perfectly fine. Thank you very much for your help! :-)